# I have set an cron job using cyberpanel but it is not working. How to resolve that?

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-9, ubuntu-20.04, cyber-panel

I'm using PHP Laravel 9 framework and cyberpanel is installed on my server. Operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.

I have created cron job in my webapp. It is working fine using SSH but after setting cron job on panel it is not working.

Command path as below:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/php /home/(domain_name)/public_html/(project_directory)/artisan Create:Mailforemail > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have tried to change the command path as domain specific and root directory but did not work for me.

I have also tried to restart cron service but it did not work also.

Comment: The `artisan` executable does _not_ reside in the `public` folder, did you change that?

Comment: it was typing mistake in path pardon for that.